# The solution of the equation has been solved, why did the software report such a prompt?

Tags: equation-solving

Running the code below:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
Reduce[{A != B, c == Sqrt[3], 
  Cos[A]^2 - Cos[B]^2 == 
   Sqrt[3] Sin[A] Cos[A] - Sqrt[3] Sin[B] Cos[B], 
  A + B + C1 == \[Pi], \[Pi] > A > 0, \[Pi] > B > 0, \[Pi] > C1 > 0, 
  sinA == Sin[A] == 4/5, sinB == Sin[B], sinC == Sin[C1], 
  a/Sin[A] == c/Sin[C1] == b/Sin[B], s == 1/2 a b Sin[C1]}, {s, a, b, 
  c, C1, sinA}, {A, B}, Reals]
```

The result has been calculated, why did such a prompt appear?

```
Reduce::ztest: Unable to decide whether numeric quantities {\[Pi]-4 ArcTan[1/2]-2 ArcTan[3/4],\[Pi]+2 ArcTan[3/4]-4 ArcTan[2]} are equal to zero. Assuming they are.
```

Comment: According to `FullSimplify`, both of those quantities are 0, so I'm not sure why Reduce gets confused about this. I guess you can ignore the warning here.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate is not the explanation here. At least it is not `PossibleZeroQ[]` in V13.3.0 that leads to the message. `Reduce[]` does not call `PossibleZeroQ[]` on the expressions in the message, and `PossibleZeroQ[]` does not have any trouble determining that the expressions are zero. Consider reporting it to WRI. It may be a minor bug. Note omitting the elimination variables `{A, B}` fixes `Reduce`; you can eliminate them after. `Reals` can be omitted, too, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Use `Block` to force the use of `FullSimplify` in place of `Simplify`, i.e., `Block[{Simplify = FullSimplify}, < your code >] `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Remove `A != B`.
- We can also use `Solve` and simplify the code.

```
sol = Solve[{c == Sqrt[3], 
   Cos[A]^2 - Cos[B]^2 == 
    Sqrt[3] Sin[A] Cos[A] - Sqrt[3] Sin[B] Cos[B], 
   A + B + C1 == π, π > {A, B, C1} > 0, Sin[A] == 4/5, 
   a/Sin[A] == c/Sin[C1] == b/Sin[B], {a, b, c} > 0}]
{Sin[B], Sin[C1], 1/2 a b Sin[C1], a, b, c} /. 
  sol[[1]] // FullSimplify
```

[image]